# Finding rows which match both conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe:

| Do | Re | Mi | Fa | So |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | Foo | 100 | 50 |
| 1 | 1 | Bar | 75 | 20 |
| 0 | 0 | True | 59 | 59 |
| 1 | 1 | False | 0 | 12 |

How would I go about finding all rows where the value in columns "Do" and "Re" BOTH equal 1 AND "Fa" is higher than "So"?

I've tried a couple of ways, but they first returns an error complaining of ambiguity:
`df['both_1']=((df['Do'] > df['Re']) & (df['Mi'] == df['Fa'] == 1))`

I also tried breaking it down into steps, but I realised the last step will result in me bringing in both True and False statements. I only want True.

````
    
    df['Do_1'] = df['Do'] == 1
    
    df['Re_1'] = df['Re'] == 1
    
    # This is where I realised I'm bringing in the False rows too
    df['both_1'] = (df['Do1'] == df['Re_1'])```
````

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chain mask by another `&` for bitwise `AND`:

```
df['both_1']= (df['Fa'] > df['So']) & (df['Do'] == 1) & (df['Re'] == 1)

print (df)
   Do  Re     Mi   Fa  So  both_1
0   1   0    Foo  100  50   False
1   1   1    Bar   75  20    True
2   0   0   True   59  59   False
3   1   1  False    0  12   False
```

Or if possible multiple columns in list comapre filtered columns by subset `df[['Do', 'Re']]` and test if all Trues by [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
df['both_1']= (df['Fa'] > df['So']) & (df[['Do', 'Re']] == 1).all(axis=1)
```

If need filter use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df1 = df[(df['Fa'] > df['So']) & (df['Do'] == 1) & (df['Re'] == 1)]
```

For second solution:

```
df1 = df[(df['Fa'] > df['So']) & (df[['Do', 'Re']] == 1).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can combine the three conditions using `&` (bitwise and):

```py
df[(df['Do'] == 1) & (df['Re'] == 1) & (df['Fa'] > df['So'])]
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
   Do  Re    Mi  Fa  So
1   1   1  Bar   75  20
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the solution works but was better suited to creating a second dataframe, which I didn't need.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Do':[1,1,0,1],'Re':[0,1,0,1],'Mi':['Foo','Bar',True,False],'Fa':[100,75,59,0],'Sol':[50,20,59,12]})

df.loc[np.where((df.Do == 1) & (df.Re ==1) & (df.Fa > df.Sol))[0]]

Output:
   Do  Re   Mi  Fa  Sol
    1   1   1  Bar  75   20

If you do not want to import anything else, just do this:

df.assign(keep=[1 if (df.loc[i,'Do'] == 1 and df.loc[i,'Re'] == 1 and df.loc[i,'Fa'] > df.loc[i,'Sol']) else 0 for i in df.index]).query("keep == 1").drop('keep',axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I haven't tried it because I was hoping to avoid further imports